# How do I find the domain of this two variable function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[The function here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82lbq.gif)
$$z(x,y) = \arcsin((y-2)/x + \sqrt{xy})$$

I know that sin inverse has a domain of $[-1, 1]$
so can I say the following:

$$-1 < (y-2)/x + \sqrt{xy} < 1$$
Is it mathematically correct to multiply the inequality by $x$ even though $x$ is not a constant?

$$-x(1-\sqrt{xy}) + 2 < y < x(1+\sqrt{xy}) \mathrm{\ for\ all\ } x > 0$$
$$-x(1-\sqrt{xy}) + 2 > y > x(1+\sqrt{xy}) \mathrm{\ for\ all\ } x < 0$$

so if I substitute $(x,y) = (-1, -1)$ in 2nd inequality I would get
$2 > -1 > -2$.  So since the inequality is true does that mean that the point $(-1,-1)$ is defined on the function given in the beginning?

What if I use domain intersections? 
The domain of $(y-2)/x$ is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \ne 0\}$,
the domain of $\sqrt{xy}$ is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : xy > 0\}$,
and the domain of the sin inverse function is $[-1, 1]$,
so does that mean it's the intersection of those three?

Comment: You know from the outset that $x\ne 0$ so you have two inequalities: $$-1\le \frac{y-2}{x}+\sqrt{xy}<0 \text{ or }0< \frac{y-2}{x}+\sqrt{xy}\le 1$$ To solve you must consider the case when  $x<0$ and $y\le0$ and the case when $x>0$ and $y\ge0$.

Comment: I cannot understand why 0 was put on the sides of the inequalities.